# When is the sigma-algebra generated by closed convex sets the same as the Borel sigma-algebra

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, topological-vector-spaces

For which topological vector spaces $E$ do we have the equality between the sigma algebra generated by the closed **convex** subsets of $E$ and the Borel sigma algebra of $E$ ?

More precisely, do we have equality for separable spaces? and for separable Hilbert spaces ?

Comment: In a separable normed space, every open set is a countable union of closed balls, so the closed balls and hence the closed convex sets will generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: You should get the same for any separable locally convex space induced by a countable family of seminorms.  I wonder whether it is true for $L^p$, $p < 1$.